# Solutions Tab is unavailable in Settings Tab under Customization to upload sample html file

Tags: dynamics-crm

[image]

I want to upload HTML page in MS Dynamics. As per my search in google, they are uploading in Solutions tab.  But the Solutions tab is unavailable for me. I have Developer access.

Comment: edit your question add some screenshot, show us where exactly are you in CRM and what you cannot see. Also which version of CRM online onprem. More details will help you get answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Make sure you have System administrator & System customizer security roles under your user profile (You should have this as you are seeing `Customizations` subarea under `Customization` group in `Settings` area).
2. Check if you see `Customize the system` when you click the `Customizations` subarea. If so you can create web resource (upload HTML file) from there also with default publisher & prefix like `new_`
3. You will see `Solutions` options as well there
4. Check with your team mates if someone modified the `Sitemap` to hide the `Solutions` subarea

[image]